# Calculate difference in row values based on other row values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to calculate the difference between endTime and startTime for their corresponding IDs
and display ID and duration(calculated field) without having to create a new table in SQL.

I have tried ordering the table and using LAG and LEAD but that gives the difference of all rows.

| ID | TypeTime | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | startTime | April 26, 2022, 12:38 PM |
| 1 | endTime | April 26, 2022, 12:39 PM |
| 2 | startTime | April 26, 2022, 12:45 PM |
| 2 | endTime | April 26, 2022, 12:49 PM |
| 3 | startTime | April 28, 2022, 11:24 PM |
| 3 | endTime | April 28, 2022, 11:30 PM |

The result should look something like this:

| ID | Duration (s) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 60 |
| 2 | 240 |
| 3 | 360 |

Comment: What happened to `ID` 3?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes ID 3 would also be there. It is just an example of the results.

Comment: @Jens I have tried ordering the table and using LAG and LEAD but that gives the difference of all rows.

Comment: Please add your statement to the question.

Comment: @ErgestBasha Yes they are. If there is a startTime then it is must to also have an endTime when the data is entered. So that is not an issue.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `DateTime` column?

Comment: @Barmar datetime format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that for each ID there is a start and end time, you may use min and max functions as the following:

```
SELECT id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(DateTime), MAX(DateTime)) AS duration
FROM 
table_name
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/bo8fYkqY).

Answer (score 1):

Use a self-join:

```
SELECT t1.id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, t1.datetime, t2.datetime) AS duration
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.typetime = 'startTime' AND t2.typetime = 'endTime'
```

Comment: Can I self-join a table that is a resultant of other joins?

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.x, use a CTE for the other joins, then self-join the CTE.

Comment: If not, either define a view for the other joins, or write them twice in the query.